# Const array with variables from another const array

Tags: c, arrays, constants

I have an constant array like this:

```
const int foo[NUM] = {
    9000,
    4400,
    620,
    480,
    1620
};
```

How can I create another const array that will do some math operations on the variables from foo? I tried this:

```
const int bar[NUM] = {
    foo[0] / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2),
    foo[1] / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2),
    foo[2] / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2),
    foo[3] / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2),
    foo[4] / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2)
};
```

However this doesnt work, it returns errors:

**Error 2   (near initialization for 'bar[0]')**, for all elements

**Error 1   initializer element is not constant**, for all elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C `const`s are not real constants, as described in this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constasconst.html). As such, the compiler only enforces that you can't write to them. For all other uses, they are not constants (the way your defines are).

---

Side note: this is one of the areas where C and C++ differ. In C++ `const` has a markedly different meaning, closer to what you are trying.

Comment: But even if I dont use const, just use int I get same errors... How can I fix this?

Comment: Removing `const` is not the solution. My answer was pointing out the reason it is not working. You can just use defines everywhere.

Comment: I cant really, some functions depend on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

[*cnicutar*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) gives [the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27887574/694576).

A possible work-around still following the [DRY-principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) would be:

```
#define FOO_0 (9000)
#define F00_1 (4400)
...

const int foo[NUM] = {
  FOO_0,
  FOO_1,
  ...
};

const int bar[NUM] = {
  FOO_0 / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2),
  FOO_1 / (DEFINE1* DEFINE2),
  ...
};
```

Comment: I could use this, but the problem is I have another array that uses variables from bar... Is there another way? Its not necessary to use const int.